# IONIC 2 Cloud Push Not Working - App Crashes

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created IONIC 2 App and at the final stage I am trying to implement the IONI Cloud Push but it is not working and every time App crashing whenever I enable the cloud push register function:

```
            this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
          return this.push.saveToken(t);
        }).then((t: PushToken) => {
          console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
        });
```

I am running the build using '**ionic run android'** in my real device

Please help me what i am doing wrong. have checked many articles everywhere it says same process what I have already implemented:-

```
npm install @ionic/cloud-angular --save
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=12341234 --save
ionic io init
```

and all other configurations.

Below is my app.component.ts

```
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TabsComponent } from '../pages/tabs/tabs-component/tabs.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../pages/login/login-component/login.component';

import { Push, PushToken } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
//import { Push } from 'ionic-native';
//import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
//import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from "@ionic-native";


@Component({
    templateUrl: './app.html',
})

export class BanglaliveApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

    rootPage = TabsComponent;
    user: any;

    pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, category: any}>;

    constructor(
        public push: Push,
        public platform: Platform,
        private storage: Storage,
        private toastController: ToastController,
        public events: Events
        ) {

        this.initializeApp();

        events.subscribe('userloggedin', user => {  
          if(user){
            this.user = user;
          }
        });

        storage.get('wordpress.user').then((value) => {
            if (value) {
                this.user = value;
            } 
        });

        this.pages = [
          { title: '????? ????', component: TabsComponent, category: { class:'home' }},
          { title: '?????????', component: LoginComponent, category: {class: 'category'}}
        ];

    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Enable RTL Support
            // this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
            Splashscreen.hide();


// ############## P U S H ###############
            this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
              return this.push.saveToken(t);
            }).then((t: PushToken) => {
              console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
            });


            // this.push.rx.notification()
            // .subscribe((msg) => {
            //  alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
            // });
// ############## P U S H ###############


        });
    }


    openPage(page, index) {

        //check if page or post has been called
            this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
        }
    }

    login(){
        this.nav.push(LoginComponent);      
    }

    logout() {
        this.user = undefined;
        this.storage.remove('wordpress.user');
        this.nav.setRoot(LoginComponent);
    }

    profile() {     
        this.nav.push(ProfilePage);
    }
}
```

and here is my app.module.ts:-

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module'
import { TabsModule } from '../pages/tabs/tabs.module';
import { SignUpModule } from '../pages/signup/signup.module'; //SSSS
import { ProfileModule } from '../pages/profile/profile.module'; //SSSS
import { MyApp} from './app.component';


import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'XXXXXX',
  },
  'push': {
    'sender_id': 'XXXXXXXX',
    'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true
      },
      'android': {
        'iconColor': '#343434'
      }
    }
   }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      backButtonIcon: 'arrow-back'
    }),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings),
    SharedModule,
    TabsModule,
    SignUpModule,
    ProfileModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please help..!!

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the plugin url?

Comment: I think this one - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push but I followed ionic docs https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/

Comment: What is the correct way? @suraj

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly fine for me on real device.

**Play with** [**Git Repo**](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/CloudPushNotification).

[image]

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Push, PushToken } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, public push: Push) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
        return this.push.saveToken(t);
      }).then((t: PushToken) => {
        console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
      });

      this.push.rx.notification()
        .subscribe((msg) => {
          alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
        });


    });
  }
}
```

***app.module.ts***

```
import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': '525f53a4'
  },
  'push': {
    'sender_id': '837506444622',
    'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true
      },
      'android': {
        'iconColor': '#343434'
      }
    }
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ],
  imports: [
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ],
  providers: [
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the outdated cordova splash plugin was causing this error and reinstall was not upgrading because in config.xml had the old version of the plugin.

I just deleted the plugin and removed lines from config.xml and reinstalled and it worked.

Just in case it may work for someone else also.